# ¿Como se cambia la orientacion de la pagina con la libreria de mPDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

tengo un problema con un pdf generado con la libreria de mPDF, necesito cambiar la orientacion de la pagina de vertical a horizontal...alguien me puede ayudar??

Comment: bienvenido al sitio Miguel! es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio ¿Cual es el código, aporta más información, te sugiero revisar [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Facíl:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['orientation' => 'L']);
```

Por default es P (Portrait / Verticar).

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf (['mode' => 'utf-8','format' => 'A4-L']);
```

Al colocar **utf-8** no obtendras errores con los acentos o caracteres especiales usados en el pdf.

**A4-L** defines el tamaño de la hoja y la orientación. Como dice Ismael la orientacion por defecto es P= (Portrait / Vertical) y L= (Landscape / Horizontal)

Comment: Por favor, tienes que dar más detalle del código, no sólo basta con ponerlo, sino tienes que explicar y dar contexto del mismo